# Create Soap Auth request in PHP

Tags: php, soap

I'm new with SOAP and trying to connect it with PHP but without positive results. Maybe you can give me a hand

**SOAP 1.2 Request**

```
POST /XXXservice.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: XXX.prueba.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetAcData xmlns="https://prueba.com/">
      <Userid>string</Userid>
      <Password>string</Password>
    </GetAcData>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

**SOAP 1.2 Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetAcDataResponse xmlns="https://prueba.com/">
      <XX>xml</GetAcDataResult>
    </GetAcDataResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

I used the following code but I'm getting this message:

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://XXX.YYYY.com/XXXservice.asmx' : Premature end of data in tag html line 3

```
<?php
    $options = array(
            'Userid' => 'xx',
            'Password' => 'xx',
        );

        $client = new SoapClient("https://XXX.YYYY.com/XXXservice.asmx", $options);
        $result = $client('GetAcData');

?>
```

Comment: Try using `.asmx?wsdl` instead of `.asmx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need an endpoint url of your webservice, that provides you the wsdl content. As @camelsWrittenInCamelCase has written in his comment, you should try `https://XXX.YYYY.com/XXXservice.asmx?wsdl` instead of `https://XXX.YYYY.com/XXXservice.asmx`.

Next you should wrap all your soap client stuff in a try/catch block, to get all possible exceptions and the most informations in case of an error.

```
try {
    $client = new \SoapClient(
        'https://XXX.YYYY.com/XXXservice.asmx?wsdl',
        [
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
            'exceptions' => true,
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
            'trace' => true,
        ]
    );
} catch (\SoapFault $fault) {
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($fault);
    echo "</pre>";

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
    echo "</pre>";

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($client->__getLastResponse());
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

As shown in the example above the soap client is initialized with an options array. We use the trace option, to enable tracing for getting the last send request and response. Additionally wie use the exception option, to force the client to throw exceptions in case of any error. Further more we disable caching the wsdl settings as long as you are developing. If you are going into production, this option should be set to `WSDL_CACHE_DISK` or `WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY`.

Now you need to know, which functions and types (complex types) your webservice provides. For this purpose you can do the following.

```
// getting the functions of your webservice
echo "<pre>";
var_dump( $client->__getFunctions() );
echo "</pre>";

// getting the types of your webservice
echo "<pre>";
var_dump( $client->__getTypes() );
echo "</pre>";
```

Since I do not know the exact scope of your web service, I'll just assume that the webservice delivers a method called `DetAcData` with two parameters `Userid` and `Password`. With this informations I can only guess, how the right call could look like. For detailed informations I 'd need the output of `__getFunctions()` and `__getTypes()`.

An examplary call could look like this.

```
try {
    $client = new \SoapClient(
        'https://XXX.YYYY.com/XXXservice.asmx?wsdl',
        [
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
            'exceptions' => true,
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
            'trace' => true,
        ]
    );

    $data = new \stdClass();
    $data->Userid = 'YourUserId';
    $data->Username = 'YourUsername';

    $result = $client->GetAcData($data);

    // $result will be an object
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($result);
    echo "</pre>"; 
} catch (\SoapFault $fault) {
    // error handling
}
```

Further more you can write data objects for every complex type mentioned in the functions and types output from your webservice. You can add a classmap to the options array when instantiating your soap client, so that every response and request will automatically be parsed in the corresponding data object. How soap client classmaps work is explained in the php documentation.

Just have a try. I 'm sure you will get it on your own. ;)